# MySQL query: How can I find top 5 images in each brand ?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, top-n

The following data in mysql table.

```
brand_id|image_id|downloads
--------|--------|---------
8       |9       |8    
35      |2829    |4    
28      |2960    |3    
28      |2961    |3    
28      |3041    |3    
35      |2831    |3    
28      |2965    |3    
35      |2832    |3    
28      |2959    |2    
28      |2976    |2    
35      |2894    |2
```

How can I find top 5 images with `GROUP_CONCAT` function in each brand ?
And I would like to get following in return :

```
brand_id|image_ids                
--------|--------------------------
8       |9                       
35      |2829,2831,2832,2894     
28      |2960,2961,3041,2965,2959
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**SUBSTRING_INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT
  brand_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(image_id SEPARATOR ','),',',5) AS image_ids
FROM Table1
GROUP BY brand_id
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13e7c/3)**

Comment: This doesn't get the top 5 of each group, just up to 5 of each group.

Comment: The data is already sorted by downloads from inner query so @Praveen Prasannan query provides correct result, but i just want to know, table have 2MILION records so this query taking 3.408 second in execution, any other faster way?

Comment: huhh. that is pain. You should try to break whenever you get 5 records for each branch id. I don't know anything as now. :( . Let me try

Answer (score 3):

If your pint is to get the **top 5** of each group, then the below sql will give you the result:

```
SELECT A.brand_id, GROUP_CONCAT(A.image_id)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2  
    ON t1.brand_id = t2.brand_id  AND t1.image_id = t2.image_id AND t1.downloads <= t2.downloads
    GROUP BY t1.brand_id, t1.image_id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
) A GROUP BY A.brand_id
```

***[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13e7c/8)***

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1667a/1 . look.. it is not returning just 5. it is returning all

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan That depends on how you read `top 5`, there could be multiple images with same downloads.